# Is it possible to submit web-based mobile apps into the Android Market or App Store?

Tags: android, iphone, ios, ios5

I've developed a web-based mobile application using Jquery Mobile and HTML5. Now, can I create an iPhone Application that has only a browser inside that runs the my application ? so that when the use clicks on the Application icon, it redirects him to the URL of my application. Can I do that with Android Market as well ?

If not allowed, what's the best way to make access to the web-based app easy ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per `App Store Review Guidelines`

There is a chance that your application may get rejected e.g.

```
2. Functionality
   2.12
     Apps that are not very useful, are simply web sites bundled as apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected

12. Scraping and aggregation
   12.3
     Apps that are simply web clippings, content aggregators, or a collection of links, may be rejected
```

Answer (score 3):

1. If it is a useful app (worth having in a mobile device) it won't get rejected.
2. Don't have your corporate website's mobile version as an app. But you can go for something like this http://itunes.apple.com/lk/app/south-wales-fire-crime-unit/id459417012?mt=8
3. Follow apple's UI standards
4. You can load your web page inside a UIWebView. You can do this either by over the internet or having the files inside the app bundle.